# Why does the XTSE1015 Error occur when sorting XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for some help with an XSL error. It's called XTSE1015 which stands for "An xsl:sort element with a select attribute must be empty". It happens when i try to output file to xml or text. Software such as Oxygen XML Editor or event Notepad++ show this error. I can't find any solution to this, well except not using sort but that is not a proper solution. Somebody stumbled upon this problem maybe and has some advice or something?

```
<xsl:variable name="strName">
   <xsl:for-each select="Samochody/Model/Nazwa">
      <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" data-type="number">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:sort>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<xsl:sort... />` element is not allowed to have any children. Hence the error. See, for example, [here at Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_sort.htm).
So, to make it work, change your code to

```
<xsl:variable name="strName">
   <xsl:for-each select="Samochody/Model/Nazwa">
      <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" data-type="number" />
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Alright, now I understand. It's kinda misleading tho because the Visual Studio Code extensions suggest otherwise:

<xsl:sort select="">
                
</xsl:sort>

Guess i shouldn't trust them more than the documentation itself lol. Anyway, thank you very much and have a nice day (or night)!

Comment: Actually xsl:sort is like many other elements in that (in 2.0+) it can have either a `select` attribute, or contained instructions, but not both. The contained instruction is an alternative way of computing the sort key, and is generally used only if this is a complex calculation, for example if it requires a call on `xsl:call-template` or `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: Thank you for this addition. I checked [Saxonica](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/xsl-elements/sort.html), but only found an example of an `xsl:sort` with children for [xsl:evaluate](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/xsl-elements/evaluate.html). This may be handy for XSLT-2.0+.